# Can I have a javascript/node backend without running a server on top of it?

Tags: javascript

EDIT

My previous question was a bit unclear, I'll try to rephrase.
Here's my need:

- I have a content accessible behind authentication (specifically IBM Portal)
- I have to expose just this specific content, to put it in a news monitor inside the intranet
- This portal is also accessible on internet
- I'd like to have a simple page that makes the required authentication, gets the content and gives it back for showing
- I don't want to have security risks (I don't want to alter IBM Portal security for just 1 content, I don't want to risk that user/password used for authentication are exposed
- I don't want / hardly can add another server / service...this ideally should be standalone (I have a web app server but I cannot use it, and I don't want to install a brand new one)

Thank you in advance!

============================

OLD QUESTION

I'm asking a rather odd question.
I'd like to build a very very small piece of code (I asked javascript, but not bound to it) that makes an authentication to a service, gets some info and gets them back.
Now, I care about the following:

- I need to access this code with an http call, be it a page with some JS calling it or whatever
- do not add more servers/services running that someone needs to manage (this has to work "serverless")
- since I'm gonna make an authentication, I don't want this piece of code to be available to someone calling it, hence why this needs to stay on the server, be "callable" but not downloadable

Is it possible to achieve something like that? Or do I need a server/API in order to do such operation "safely"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `I need to access this code with an http call` this requires a web server by definition. But yes, you can write a small, single purpose node server that does that. (also, a backend *is* a server)

Comment: @ChrisG beat me to it by 1 second.

Comment: What you consider serverless if you are using it in AWS / Azure sense, is that someone else is hosting a server for you.

Comment: I've probably put the question in a wrong way. I have an HTTPServer, and I'd like to put a page on it that gives back these info I need, but since this requires some authentication, I don't want the risk to expose the code running it. Hence the "backend" of this page must be runnable but not downloadable by the page itself...is it possible? My mind says no, but maybe I'm not aware of some new technology @ChrisG

Comment: I mean, I can do in many ways, like PhP or NodeJS server etc etc, but my current situation calls for something "standalone"

Comment: Backend code is never visible to the user. What you describe is how a backend already works: user makes request, code runs on server, result is sent to user/browser. You've used PHP, so you should know this: linking to a php script in the browser will not show the source code but the result of calling it on the server. It sounds like you're asking for cURL? Or node's `http` package?

Comment: Just to clarify this: are you asking how to make an HTTP request to some other website, but on the backend? If so: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: @ChrisG i've update my question to be more clear, thank you advance

Comment: Like I said: use node/PHP/whatever to make the authenticated request, grab the content and echo it. None of your node/PHP/whatever code is visible to anybody, unless they have direct access to the server (like you).

Comment: So you 1) need a server, you 2) do have a server, but 3) you cannot use it and 4) don't want to add a server? In that case what you're asking is impossible. I also find it mildly irritating that you don't answer my comments but keep editing the question. If you are waiting for somebody to come along telling you something different than I did, it's not going to happen.

Comment: 1) since the question wasn't well posed, I found not only usefull but polite to edit the question so whoever sees it can have a clear picture of the request and the reply, to be useful for everybody. As far as I know this should be the norm on SO

2) I have and can use an HTTP server, I have and cannot use a WebApp server, that's the problem, so I cannot create java webapp exposing rest services, for example

3) thank you for you penultimate reply. it's still not clear to me how can the JS code be safe if is included in the page itself: can you provide an example?

Thanks @ChrisG

Comment: Nobody said anything about client-side JS; that's most likely not going to work anyway due to CORS. node means server-side JS, exactly like PHP or Java. What kind of HTTP server are we talking about? Is it completely static? I can't imagine a company's intranet server is just Apache or the like.

Comment: @ChrisG is a simple IBM HTTP Server, shipped with the IBM Portal. Basically an Apache. I'll look into your last solution. Thank you again!

Comment: If the portal runs on the server, and the portal supports logins, it cannot be just Apache; there has to be some form of backend language. How else would the page manage logins and access its user database?

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to respond to an HTTP request then you need an HTTP server. There is no getting around that.

You can minimise the amount of management by pushing off the work of managing the server to someone else, e.g. Amazon Lambda (which bills itself as "Serverless" but that just means that they expect you to just think about the web service and leave the management of Node, the OS, and the hardware to them).

---

> I have an HTTPServer, and I'd like to put a page on it that gives back these info I need, but since this requires some authentication, I don't want the risk to expose the code running it. Hence the "backend" of this page must be runnable but not downloadable by the page itself...is it possible? My mind says no

Having server-side code which will run and send its output as an HTTP resource while not making its source code available to arbitrary clients is the **usual** behaviour of *any* server-side code.

You can't download Google's search engine by visiting `http://google.com/`. You can't download Yahoo's email software so you could run it on your LAN by visiting `http://mail.yahoo.com/`.